# Store extra (meta) data about nodes

Tags: 8, nodes

I would like to store some extra (meta) data about my nodes. Exactly like the `promote` or `sticky` columns in the `node_field_data` table.

In Drupal 7, I sometimes solved this problem by binding an extra property onto the node object. To add an extra column to the node table, I used code something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function mymodule_install() {

  // Add foo field to node table.
  $spec = array(
    'description' => 'Some description.',
    'type' => 'int',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'initial' => 0,
  );
  $keys_new['indexes'] = array('foo' => array('foo'));
  if (!db_field_exists('node', 'foo')) {
    db_add_field('node', 'foo', $spec, $keys_new);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_schema_alter().
 */
function mymodule_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['node']['fields']['foo'] = array(
    'description' => 'Some description.',
    'type' => 'int',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  db_drop_field('node', 'foo');
}
```

I'd then add a field to the node form and save values, on submission, with something like `node_save()`.

I also solved the problem using a tracking table. Simply creating a custom table schema and creating some CRUD operations to alter the values in the table via a form.

For the users table there was a special column, called *data*, if I remember correctly, where extra user settings could be defined and stored.

What is the best way to do this in Drupal 8?

Comment: The best way has to be to use fields - that's literally what they're designed for. You can use `hook_entity_base_field_info` to provide new ones in a few lines

Comment: @Clive why in a comment? You provided the correct answer.

Comment: No time @ssibal, hopefully someone will be able to flesh that comment out into an answer (or I'll come back to it later)

Comment: Do you mean use a regular field? To be clear I'm not saving 'content', which would create a new revision. It's meta data about the node.

Comment: A field is definitely the easiest way to go. You can add your field and then in the form display set it to disabled so it won't appear in the back end editing form for users. But you'll still be able to easily access the field value or modify the field through the CMS like any other field

Comment: My content type is set set to automatically create a new revision. If I add a field to store my meta data, altering the value would create a new content revision, this would be messy (revisions, content moderation etc.) because the _content_ is unchanged.

Comment: Well, in this case if you feel that the meta data should not affect the revisions, I vote for the tracking table solution, which is nicely loosely coupled. (from extension point of view)